# Apps Script/Google Sheets: Reduce function execution time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**How can I reduce function's execution item?**

Currently the function executes row by row and would like the function to execute for all rows at once.

**Script function:**
When a cell value is added/edited (for 6 sheets), the entire row's Font color is changed to Red for tracking purposes. After the rows in Red have been verified by the user, the sheet needs to be 'Reset' for future use. This is initiated by the user selecting the 'RESET Sheet selected' button on the Summary Sheet (actions occur).

- Edited rows reset from Red, to their pre-defined font colors
- Qty reset to 0 (column H)
- Suppress reset to unchecked (column O)

**Currently the function Resets row by row and would like the function to execute for all rows in a sheet at once.**

The Summary sheet contains a Drop-down list of all child sheets in the spreadsheet.

[Dummy Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DELsVaEgkiMSvjD-maUY_bfUCy8IIYSKbw1EkTlA6gM/edit#gid=381151058)

```
function resetSelectedSheet() {

  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Get the Active Spreadsheet

   var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Summary")
   const target_sheet_name = source_sheet.getRange(4,10).getDisplayValue() 

  let sheet = ss.getSheetByName(target_sheet_name); // Access the sheet by its name

  for (x = 1; x < 150; x++) {  
   for (y = 1; y < 20; y++) {

  let rangeToCheck = sheet.getRange(x,y); // v2, updated with For Loop 
  let valueToCheck = rangeToCheck.getBackgrounds(); // Get its value

  let resultRange = sheet.getRange(x,y); // v2, updated with For Loop 
  let zeroRange = sheet.getRange(x,8); // v2, updated with For Loop  
  let suppressRange = sheet.getRange(x,15); // v2, updated with For Loop  

  if (valueToCheck == "#f2cda0") // light orange background
  {
      resultRange.setFontColor("#333399")
      zeroRange.setValue(0.00);      // Reset Qty values to '0' in column H
      suppressRange.setValue(false); // uncheck all Suppress checkboxes in column O 
      suppressRange.setFontColor("#333399")
  } 
  
  
  else if (valueToCheck == "#969696") // dark grey background

  {
    resultRange.setFontColor("#ffffff") // set Font color to White


  } else if (valueToCheck == "#ccffcc") // light green background

  {
    resultRange.setFontColor("#008000")

  }

    else if (valueToCheck == "#ffff99") // light yellow background
  {
        resultRange.setFontColor("#993300")
  }


    else if (valueToCheck == "#c9daf8") // light blue background
  {
        resultRange.setFontColor("Black")
        zeroRange.setValue(0.00);     // Reset Qty values to 0 
  }


      else if (valueToCheck == "#c0c0c0") // light grey background
  {
        resultRange.setFontColor("Orange") // set Font color to Color
  }


      else if (valueToCheck == "#000000") // black background

  {
        resultRange.setFontColor("#ffffff") // set Font color to White
  }

   }
 }
     ss.toast("Amounts have been Reset from selected Sheet");

}
```

Comment: [What types of Questions Should I Avoid Asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost of your script.

I think that when `setFontColor`, `setValue` and so on are used in the loop, the process cost will become high. In your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function resetSelectedSheet() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Get the Active Spreadsheet
  var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Summary")
  const target_sheet_name = source_sheet.getRange(4, 10).getDisplayValue()
  let sheet = ss.getSheetByName(target_sheet_name); // Access the sheet by its name

  // I modified the below script.
  const obj = { "#f2cda0": "#333399", "#969696": "#ffffff", "#ccffcc": "#008000", "#ffff99": "#993300", "#c9daf8": "Black", "#c0c0c0": "Orange", "#000000": "#ffffff" };
  const range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 149, 19);
  const fontColors = range.getFontColorObjects();
  const values = range.getValues();
  range.getBackgrounds().forEach((r, i) => {
    r.forEach((c, j) => {
      fontColors[i][j] = obj[c] || fontColors[i][j];
      if (c == "#f2cda0") {
        values[i][7] = 0;
        values[i][14] = false;
        fontColors[i][14] = "#333399";
      } else if (c == "#c9daf8") {
        values[i][7] = 0;
      }
    });
  });
  range.setValues(values).setFontColors(fontColors);
  ss.toast("Amounts have been Reset from selected Sheet");
}
```

- In this modification, the font colors and the values are overwritten by the updated values. By this, `setValues` and `setFontColors` are used one time, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for providing guidance, this was very helpful @Tanaike